# Twit pic photo upload with PlainOauth Library

Tags: iphone, oauth, twitpic

I am using Twit pic in my app with following example.

[PlainOAuth](https://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth)

It was working fine and suddenly It is not uploading images.

Message on console is :

> Got HTTP status code from TwitPic: 401

I don't know whats the problem .please help

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961298/twit-pic-api-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twit Pic Api Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961298/twit-pic-api-error)